# The word for a prolonged "f" sound

Tags: vocabulary

[mystery word] is to "f" as sibilant is to "s", in other words. Please help me out. This is driving me mental.

Comment: "Off-the-cuff stuff" is a fragment I can think of right now for which such a word would be suited.

Comment: The word "fricative" is used in audio testing, usually by pronounced the "ffffffricative".

Comment: @jimm101 "fricative" is the correct answer.

Comment: According to a bit of research, "s" and "z" are also two fricative sounds. How can this be, when I know that "s" is a sibilant? (Is "z" a sibilant too? It seems like a modified "s" to me.) Are all sibilants fricatives, too? Going to look this up right now.

Answer (score 1):

In audio testing, ***fricative*** is used.

> a consonant characterized by frictional passage of the expired breath through a narrowing at some point in the vocal tract

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fricative)